# how to get unixtimestamp from variable

Tags: variables, timestamp

I have dates stored in a mysql database in the default date format YYYY-MM-DD using field name "depDate".
I need to retrieve and convert them to a UNIXTIMESTAMP format to compare with other dates.

Wed, 01 Jan 2014 12:00:00 GMT is "1388577600" and 
Wed, 31 Dec 2014 12:00:00 GMT is "1420027200"

```
$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(depDate), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(balDate), depPaid_czk, depositAmt FROM `tbl_finance` WHERE depositAmt > 0 ORDER BY depositAmt ASC"); 

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
$depDate = $row["depDate"];
$balDate = $row["balDate"];

echo $depDate;
echo "<br>";
echo $balDate;
```

};

I can't figure out why it doesn't work. When I use "depDate" I get output in the form of YYYY-MM-DD, but I need it in this form "1388577600".

Comment: If you want MySQL to return a Unix timestamp then get your initial query(not shown) to return `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(someColumn)` and you won't have to convert it in PHP. That said, your query looks very confused with different date & time formats everywhere. I'm sure there must be a better way.

Comment: someColumn - any column you want to put there. In your case `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(depDate)`

Comment: I still need help with this.